# Length these (/θ/ + /ð/) pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I saw a sentence in which there were two consonant sounds I couldn't pronounce. The sentence is below:

"I read at leng**th th**ese days".

In this sentence I was unable to pronounce **length** and **these**  together. How to pronounce **/θ/** of *length* and **/ð/** of *these* together?

Do we need to skip one? Can you help me, please?

Comment: Native English speakers don't try to pronounce them both. They simply ignore the original /θ/ of _length_ -- or substitute a glottal stop for it -- and just say the /ð/ in _these_, producing something that sounds like /'lɛŋʔðizdez/

Comment: @JohnLawler Have to disagree with that. I can’t really tell for sure whether there’s actually any voicing when I pronounce it, but the /θ/ is definitely there. If I skip anything, it’s the /ð/; if anything, I pronounce it [ˈlɛŋʔθiːzdeɪz]. (The glottal stop isn’t substitution for me; I pronounce _length_ in isolation as [lɛŋʔθ] as well.)

Comment: Everybody has their own fast speech rules (/fæspitʃulz/ in my case).